# how to gather vectors of different size by mpi::boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using [mpi::boost::gather](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/gather.html) to implement one algorithm which need to gather different size vectors at each node. I found it can be done by using
[MPI_gather](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node70.html). However, any suggestions on achieve it by boost library? Just wanna to make the code consistently. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [`boost::gatherv()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/gatherv.html) ?

Comment: Yes! I should have searched more. Thanks!